# gperftools cpuProfiler cannot see the simbols when profiling a file created by and ARM device

Tags: c++, profiling, gperftools

I want to profile a C++ application that runs in an ARM device.
I ran my app and I profiled it using ProfilerStart("googleProfBL.prof"), so the file is generated.
When I open the file from the ARM device in my local computer I get this:

./pprof --text --add_lib=libraryIwanttoDebug.so BinaryThatLoadsThatLibrary googleProfBL.prof 
Using local file /home/genius/PresControler/src-build-target/deploy/NavStartup.
Using local file ../traces/googleProfBL.prof.
Warning: address ffffffffffffffff is longer than address length 8
Warning: address ffffffffffffffff is longer than address length 8
Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at ./pprof line 4475.
Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at ./pprof line 4475.
Total: 5347 samples
    258   4.8%   4.8%      258   4.8% 0x76d4c276
    144   2.7%   7.5%      144   2.7% 0x76da2cc4
    126   2.4%   9.9%      126   2.4% 0x5d0f8284
    114   2.1%  12.0%      114   2.1% 0x76d27386
     64   1.2%  13.2%       64   1.2% 0x76dba2dc
     53   1.0%  14.2%       53   1.0% 0x76dba1f4
      ...

The so library is compiled in debug mode (is not stripped), I do not know why I am not getting the symbols.

I tried this:

`./pprof --text --add_lib=aFileOfTheLibrary.o BinaryThatLoadsThatLibrary googleProfBL.prof 
Looks like I got a couple of symbols.
Using local file /home/genius/PresControler/src-build-target/deploy/NavStartup.
Using local file ../traces/googleProfBL.prof.
Warning: address ffffffffffffffff is longer than address length 8
Warning: address ffffffffffffffff is longer than address length 8
Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at ./pprof line 4475.
Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at ./pprof line 4475.
Total: 5347 samples
     258   4.8%   4.8%      258   4.8% 0x76d4c276
     144   2.7%   7.5%      144   2.7% 0x76da2cc4
     126   2.4%   9.9%      126   2.4% 0x5d0f8284
     114   2.1%  12.0%      114   2.1% 0x76d27386
      64   1.2%  13.2%       64   1.2% 0x76dba2dc
      53   1.0%  14.2%       53   1.0% 0x76dba1f4
      50   0.9%  15.1%       50   0.9% 0x76dbf1bc
      34   0.6%  15.8%       34   0.6% 0x72eae1b4
      30   0.6%  16.3%       30   0.6% 0x76d8a32a
      30   0.6%  16.9%       30   0.6% 0x76d8e2c0
..
0   0.0% 100.0%        7   0.1% std::forward_as_tuple <- I couldn't see that before!!!`

I tried doing --add_lib for every .o I have but I do not get any more symbols. Why I do not get the symbols, does it have anything to do because I am checking the results using an intel and getting them using an ARM?? How could I fix that? any help???
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I got much more information now!
I was living my application pressing ctrl+c, so the file got somehow corrupt...
I did a test calling ProfilerStop() before pressing ctrl+c and it worked (of course using as well --lib_prefix where the .so are).
I still got these warnings:

    `Warning: address ffffffffffffffff is longer than address length 8
    Warning: address ffffffffffffffff is longer than address length 8
    Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at ./pprof line 4475.
    Hexadecimal number > 0xffffffff non-portable at ./pprof line 4475.`

If someone knows why I am getting them (I assume is because I am debugging code generated by another device) please let me know.